# Parsing DateTime string using NodaTime

Tags: datetime, nodatime

How can we parse a Zoned DateTime string using NodaTime? I am currently using LocalDateTimePattern for parsing, but I think that the DateTime value yielded would be in the **Server's timezone.**

```
var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(dateTimePattern);

var parseResult = pattern.Parse(dateTimeString);
if (!parseResult.Success)
{
   // throw an exception or whatever you want to do
}
```

I came across ZonedDateTime pattern when I was looking at the 
 [Noda Time API](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/api/?topic=html/T_NodaTime_Text_ZonedDateTimePattern.htm). But, I am not able to use it. Am I missing out something?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which version of Noda Time you're using, but I suspect it's 1.1.0 (that is, the latest released version).

`ZonedDateTimePattern` is only available in the development version of Noda Time (which will become 1.2.0 when it's released); as mentioned in [the roadmap](http://nodatime.org/developer/roadmap.html), 1.2.0 will include better text handling, including parsing for `ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime`.

I'm afraid that in 1.1.x there's no way to parse a `ZonedDateTime` directly (as noted in the [limitations](http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/limitations.html) section of the 1.1.x user guide), though you could parse an `Instant` and a timezone name separately, and construct a `ZonedDateTime` by hand.